Why the functions Contravariance with their paramaters in typescript?
I have recently studied the generic concepts in Typescript. I have a problem with understanding "Why do the functions contravariance with their parameters?". I know that:

Covariance is ifT extends U (T is assignable to U), it is true that G<T> extends G<U> (G<T> is also assignable to G<U>)

Contravariance is if T extends U, it's sure to conclude that G<U> extends G<T> (now G<U> is assignable to G<T>).


before asking the question in this forum, I read the following posts, However, I still have trouble understanding why Functions in Typescript are Contravariant in their parameters:

Why indexed access type using generics resolves to intersection?
What are covariance and contravariance?
Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript
Covariance and Contravariance in TypeScript

I see that not only functions are contravariant with their parameters in typescript, but some other languages are also true.
I feel so frustrated to accept it without finding out why it is true. Could you help me explain it or if i missing related knowledge, please tell me what it is.

"not only […] in typescript, but some other languages […] also" - I'd be surprised if there's any language where the Function type constructor is not contravariant in the parameter types?

I think your second link explains this perfectly with the example of how subtypes of functions work

@Bergi, I have read this several times, and I don't understand why Dog -> Dog is a supertype of Greyhound → Greyhound with the assumption: Greyhound ≼ Dog ≼ Animal.

It isn't. The article answers "question 1" with "no".

after reading the second link i don't understand why Greyhound → Greyhound is not subtype of Dog -> Dog, it didn't explain clearly or give any example, Therefore I don't understand although I read it much time and spent a lot of time considering  it

Assume you have a variable let f: Dog → Dog, so you can assign any value of a subtype of Dog → Dog to that variable. Now you call f(dog) (where dog is a Dog). Can you assign a function of type Greyhound → Greyhound to f, or would the call fail? You can't, as that would mean passing a Dog to a function that accepts only a Greyhound, so Greyhound → Greyhound is not a subtype of Dog → Dog.

(Instead of having a variable to which you assign a function, the article uses a function f that takes such a function as its argument - same thing)

@Bergi, i don't understand your statement: "as that would mean passing a Dog to a function that accepts only a Greyhound".  I don't know Dog you refer to is Dog type or dog variable, because you said: passing Dog to a function that accept only a Greyhound

@Bergi, if Greyhound  extend Dog , we can pass dog variable to function require param having Greyhound  type (Greyhound ->Greyhound)

No, you cannot. If Greyhound has an extra property over Dog (still extends Dog), you cannot use a Dog that doesn't have this property in a place where a Greyhound is expected. (Whereas you can use a Greyhound instance in any place where a Dog is expected).

@Bergi, I wrongly understand the mean of subtype. after considering your above comment, Can I state that " subtype is a type that substitutes for position require parent type". When I assign  Greyhound variable to Dog variable is accepted because, Greyhound is a Dog,in other words, the Greyhound can play the role of Dog (Greyhound has all properties that Dog require). Therefore, it can stand in positions that require Dog type .

Yes, precisely that

@Bergi, when the function has type Greyhound → Greyhound assign to Dog → Dog. it  is not accepted because the target function (Dog → Dog) (left side of assignment) accepts instances of Dog as argument, However source function Greyhound → Greyhound (right side of assignment) doesn't accept Dog variable as argument. So, Greyhound → Greyhound can't play a role as Dog → Dog ( not substitute for  Dog → Dog). Therefore  Greyhound → Greyhound is not a subtype of Dog → Dog

Yes, that's it!

@Bergi, the return type is reversed to params type of function. Because subtype is a supertype, subtype contains all members that supertype require. Therefore return type must be either Greyhound,other subtype of Dog or even Dog is ok.

Yes, the return type of Function is covariant

Thank you, your explanations make everything clear, thanks so much

I'll use the concrete example of Animal and Dog.
class Animal {
  move(distanceInMeters: number = 0) {
    console.log(`Animal moved ${distanceInMeters}m.`);
  }
}
 
class Dog extends Animal {
  bark() {
    console.log("Woof! Woof!");
  }
}

There are two choices for allowing assignment between Dog and Animal, are we allowed to substitute Dog for Animal, and are we able to substitute Animal for Dog.
const animal: Animal = new Dog; 
animal.move(10);

Because extends means that we have the members of the base, this is fine. Typescript allows this
const dog: Dog = new Animal;
dog.bark();

There isn't a bark method in Animal, so this would fail at runtime. Typescript forbids this.
Now let's look at function types.
const dog: Dog = new Dog;
const animal: Animal = new Animal;

type UseAnimal: (animal: Animal) => void;
type UseDog: (dog: dog) => void;

const useAnimal: UseAnimal = (animal: Animal) => { animal.move(10); }
const useDog: UseDog = (dog: Dog) => { dog.bark() }

Language designers have the same choice about function parameters. Lets see what happens when we allow the two cases
const dogFn: UseDog = useAnimal;
dogFn(dog);

Because we are passing a Dog to useAnimal it is fine, it can move(10) as above. Typescript allows this.
const animalFn: UseAnimal = useDog;
animalFn(animal)

The Animal we pass to useDog would cause a runtime failure, because it lacks bark(). Typescript forbids this.

after reading your answer, I partly understand a bit. However, I still have some unclear points, can you help me make them clear?

when i run const animalFn: UseAnimal = useDog; , compiler throw me error: Type 'UseDog' is not assignable to type 'UseAnimal'. Types of parameters 'd' and 'a' are incompatible. Property 'bark' is missing in type 'Animal' but required in type 'Dog'

@LeoPkm2-1 Yes, that's the example of something that wouldn't work. const dog: Dog = new Animal; is also an error

is the reason that why error Ts throw when implement function that has defined type like: animalFn: UseAnimal, if params access to properties or methods that don't exist ( or describe) in params type is error. Although Dog is assignable to Animal (dog could pass into Animal param), expected type (shape) of param in function (animalFn) is Animal?

Yes, you can't pass an arbitrary Animal to useDog, but you can pass an arbitrary Dog to useAnimal

When typescript sees that implementation of animalFn (it's useDog) has Dog param having a method that doesn't exist in expected param type (Animal). It immediately throws error to prevent the error like i said in the above comment?

Yes, trying to assign that is an error, because the runtime behaviour if it weren't would be bad.

,is my self-explanation about why const animalFn: UseAnimal = useDog; is prevent in Ts reasonable?

or is my explanation wrong or missing something? Please tell me what it is.

@LeoPkm2-1 Yes. but it's only half of what contravariance means. Ts had to implement a checker that accepts const dogFn: UseDog = useAnimal;, the types don't exactly match.

After considering your interesting example, I have some assumptions about why Ts accept const dogFn: UseDog = useAnimal; Could you help me check them are correct or wrong?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
